# Django rest_framework not serializing relationships

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

I am trying to serialize Foreign keys inline with Django rest_framework. Foreign keys are used to link lookup tables as per a normal DB normalisation setup.

An example of my model with the lookup:

```
class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    StatusId = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    StatusDescription = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Order(models.Model):
    OrderId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    OrderDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Status = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers:

```
class OrderStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderStatus
        fields = ['StatusId', 'StatusDescription']

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('OrderId', 'OrderDate', 'Status')
```

What I obtain when I call the REST API is the following:

```
{
    "type": "Order",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
        "OrderId": 1,
        "OrderDate": "2020-05-19T08:23:54"
     },
     "relationships": {
        "Status": {
            "data": {
                "type": "OrderStatus",
                "id": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have the Status inline in the "attributes", either as a simple id or even as a JSON object with the two values inline. Both are good options, as long as it's not in that "relationships" field.

I tried to add the following to OrderSerializer:

```
Status = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=OrderStatus.objects.all())
```

No difference.

I tried the following:

```
Status = OrderStatusSerializer(many=False)
```

No difference.

I tried all the other options in
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/docs/api-guide/relations.md
including the SlugField to include the description instead that the ID, with no result.

It seems that what I change has no effect on the serialization.

Comment: well, adding `depth = 1` in your serializer's Meta class it will serialize the linked relations as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it had no effect. Still the result is the same.

Comment: Turns out that following a tutorial I had changed the renderer to rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer. 
By switching it back to rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer it now works much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my own comment, the issue was caused by `rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer`.

By switching it back to `rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer` the expected documented behaviour has been re-established.